# Select most recent row from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to display the most recent comment and its date from a different table. The different table is keyed to the rows in the main table. Stated another way:

A "main" table is keyed to a `notes` table. The `notes` table can have any number of entries giving detail of steps taken referring to the `main` tables row, but I want only the most recent comment and date to show in my query.

The main table name is `main` keyed to table `notes. The 2 columns in`notes`I need are`entry_timestamp`and`activity_notes`.

Comment: You mention "different", "progress", "main" and "notes" tables--could you please clarify the schema of the tables?

Comment: I edited out the "progress." Now only the real names are given and the table names are in quotes. Sorry.

Comment: Could you possibly give the schema of your tables? From your question, it looks like you just want the most recent `entry_timestamp` from `notes` and its corresponding `activity_notes`, also from `notes`. In this case `main` table is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
select
  (select activity_notes from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1)
  , (select entry_timestamp from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1)
from main m
```

Comment: mysql> select   (select top 1 activity_notes from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc)   , (select top 1 entry_timestamp from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc) from main m;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 activity_notes from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp d' at line 1

Comment: MySQL has no `TOP n`. You have to use the equivalent `LIMIT n`

Comment: @ypercube: I changed it like you said and got this:   `mysql> select   (select LIMIT 1 activity_notes from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc)   , (select LIMIT 1 entry_timestamp from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc) from main m
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1 activity_notes from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_times' at line 1
mysql>`

Comment: @CaptainClaptrap, `LIMIT` goes *after* the `ORDER BY`, see MySQL documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - I made the changes as you suggest and got this `mysql> select   (select activity_notes from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1)   , (select entry_timestamp from notes n where n.mainId = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc  LIMIT 1) from main m;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'n.mainId' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You have to use your own column names - as you didn't post them I had to make them up.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, I don't understand what "n.mainId" refers to. The key column? the "main" table's key column is "ID". That what I should use? Are there any other made up names in your answer?

Comment: You didn't provide enough columns names so replace n.mainId = m.id with however you link table notes to table main. i.e. what is the column in table notes called that refers to table main.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, working off the assumption in my last comment I got: `mysql> select (select activity_notes from notes n where ID = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1) , (select entry_timestamp from notes n where ID = m.id order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1) from main m;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'm.entry_timestamp' in 'order clause'
`

Comment: @DaleBurrell, notes column is "main_id", so should I replace n.mainId = m.id with ID = main_id ? or would it be notes.main_id = main.ID

Comment: So you are saying the 'id' column of your 'notes' table links to the 'main' table? Sorry you need to change m.entry_timestamp => n.entry_timestamp.

Comment: Wouldn't it be n.main_id = m.id

Comment: What does the n in n.main_id stand for and what does the m in m.id stand for?

Comment: I tried both ways: `mysql> select (select activity_notes from notes n where notes.main_id = main.ID order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1) , (select entry_timestamp from notes n where notes.main_id = main.ID order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1) from main m; ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'notes.main_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: and `mysql> select (select activity_notes from notes n where n.main_id = m.ID order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1) , (select entry_timestamp from notes n where n.main_id = m.ID order by m.entry_timestamp desc LIMIT 1) from main m; ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'm.entry_timestamp' in 'order clause' mysql>`

Comment: notes n = notes as n, and main m = main as m, which are table aliases. So n becomes a shorthand way to refer to notes and m becomes a shorthand way to refer to main. Its standard practise when writing queries else you end up having to write the full table name over and over again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6680/discussion-between-dale-burrell-and-captain-claptrap)

Comment: Aha! the "m.entry_timestamp" should be "n.entry_timestamp" and now it works! Thanks for hanging in there with me!