# getting data using join from 2 table and order by latest(One to many relationship)

Tags: mysql

1. Hi,
      I am trying to fetch data from two tables using join but i am not getting any idea how to implement it.

   I have two tables

   a)Case
   it has caseid

   A single case will have many responses

   b)response
   It has responseid and caseid

   Now i want to fetch all cases order by latest responses .

   Any Help ?

Edit:-Will this support one to many relation ????? . i am looking to filter the duplicate value

Comment: THis is exactly, what i am looking . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110664/select-rows-from-one-table-join-most-recent-row-from-other-table-with-one-to-ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.caseid, r.responseid
from case c Inner Join response r ON c.caseid = r.responseid
order by r.responseid
```

This might help you a lot for further such queries.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Will this support one to many relation ????? . i am looking to filter the duplicate value ?

Comment: It will support one to many relation, values combination of (caseid, responseid) should be unique, if constraints are properly implemented.

Comment: It will not. this will fetch the duplicate case_id. I want unique case Id. i.e., the case_id with latest response will come. Those caseId, do not have Response simply return Null

Comment: @shail in your `Response` table, how do you know that the record contains the latest response for each case?

Comment: using caseid. Please see :- b)response table:- It has responseid and caseid. the lastest Responce will have obvious higher responseid and this table has date column also

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.*, r.responseid
from `case` c Inner Join `response` r ON c.caseid = r.caseid
order by r.responseid
```

Comment: use backtics(`) as case is keyword in mysql

Comment: Will this support one to many relation ????? . i am looking to filter the duplicate value ?

Comment: this will fetch the duplicate case_id. I want unique case Id. i.e., the case_id with latest response will come. Those caseId, do not have Response simply return Null